# SetLocale vs Custom Data format on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, localization

I'm working on a C++/MFC Windows application and I want that the format of the number, date, etc is correct in all over the world.

Example: Someone prefer to write a numbers with the " , " separator for the decimals, other prefer to use the dot, and so on.

I start putting the locals command at the startup of my windows application:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "" );
```

This works for language format, because when the second parameter is empty this function ask the local setting to the OS for the numbers, date, etc.

This works for the Region-> Format but not with the "Additional settings": for example, if your system format is English (United States) like in the image, and you change it through the Format list using another language with a different format for numbers, it work on my application.

For "works" I mean that the number insidet texbox, ListCtrl, etc use the correct format for decimal symbol, digit grouping, etc.

[image]

But if you go in the "Additional settings" and change the single format like decimal separator, etc without changing the forma language it doesn't work.

In this case, when I use the "setlocale" function the format of the numbers is the same of language; it does not follow the custom rules. Other programs, like Microsoft Excel, are able to show the numbers following the custom rules,

How I can do the same on my software?
How get the correct format for numbers (language format + custom settings)?

Thanks

This is the additional setting dialog: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MSDN topics:
"[Using National Language Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374144(v=vs.85).aspx)"->"[Working with Custom Locales](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374144(v=vs.85).aspx)".
Also try GetLocaleInfoEx.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can help me. With GetLocaleInfoEx I can retrieves information about a locale specified by name but what I can do after? If I suppose to retrieve the decimal separator, how I can set it on my software? I will try GetLocaleInfoEx to see what happend in my code...